how likely is it that a patent application is rejected due to poorly written boilerplate details?
I have invented a new computer implemented method for social media websites and apps, which is entirely unrelated to any hardware.
My patent attorney has drafted the application, which includes boilerplate description on standard hardware components such as computer, server, network, internet, database, etc., in order to enable the invention.
All of it looks good to me.
What are the chances that the attorney is negligent regarding the boilerplate section and left out a component, failed to be clear or define a term that is used, etc, causing the application to be rejected?

That is one reason the Patent Attorney sends the application to you to review prior to filing. You, as the inventor, are better suited to know if something is omitted. While I continue to program in my free time, I am not familiar with all of the new programming frameworks that come out every other day and whether there is something specific needed in the hardware to enable the framework. I will read up on the framework before drafting, but that doesn't make me an expert on the framework - the inventor is the expert on their invention.

Very unlike if they are an experienced registered practitioner. (Note that terms are not usually explicitly defined.)
There are several possibilities - computer implemented inventions are getting harder and harder to get allowed. Some practitioners have done a better job of keeping up with trends in what is getting allowed and drafting claims to have them get assigned to art groups with higher allowance rates.
You have probably been told that most applications are initially rejected. And you frequently get a second negative office action which is labeled “final”. It’s final until you fill out another firm and pay more money.
I wouldn’t second guess your attorney especially without much more to go on.
